# Hovering over tag links removes the title attribute

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

While inspecting the tags on the profile page, I found that the `a` tag is not proper. Probably somewhere is this being messed up in creating it dynamically

Just to clarify, the `a` tag has incomplete `title` attribute after hovering over it:

```
<a href="/search?q=user:1135954+[java]" class="post-tag" title>java</a>
```

Here is a screenshot for quick reference.

[image: tilte messed up]

Comment: [That appears to be the least of their problems.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fusers%2F246246%2Fanimuson&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: What you see in the developer tools is not necessarily the actual page source.

Comment: These are not the title tags you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the source, you can see that the original tag (to take [python](/questions/tagged/python) in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159388/murgatroid99) as an example) is:

```
<a href="/search?q=user:159388+[python]" class="post-tag" title="show all posts by this user in 'python'">
```

As you can see, the title starts with the value `show all posts by this user in 'python'`. The JavaScript in the page appears to remove it once it displays the richer hover box.

So, the source of the page is not invalid HTML5, at least for this particular thing.

Comment: Specifically there's a line in the javascript:  `b.attr("title", "")` which seems to be the culprit.  (from all.js)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even look for the JavaScript code that was doing it. I just inferred what it was doing.