# Some post tags don't have titles

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hovering over tag links removes the title attribute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145199/hovering-over-tag-links-removes-the-title-attribute)

While working on a userscript, I found a weird inconsistency in the markup of the front page of [Super User](https://superuser.com/):

[image]

Some tags don't get a value for their `title` attribute.

Comment: Is this just on Super User or on other SE sites as well?  If it's only on Super User, I'd say this should be on their meta and we can migrate it there.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas: Just checked the front page of [raspberrypi.se]. Seems to be even more wide-spread there. So, no, it doesn't seem to be an issue that's exclusive to [su].

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Just try it on the tags to the right, no title there

Comment: Any tags you haven't moused over should still have the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All tags **start off** with a title on them. If you have JavaScript enabled, that title gets removed in order to prevent it from showing up along with the site's generated black pop up box **the moment you hover over it** (even if the black pop up doesn't actually finish loading). They just never get replaced, and it really doesn't matter if they do or not because you have JavaScript enabled - you get the fancier black pop ups!

Anyways, they *are* there for those who do not have JavaScript enabled and need real titles.

Comment: I have fancy boxes on all tags but only some are missing the `title`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: I've tested this plenty. Viewing the source of a page as soon as it loads, every single tag has a title. The moment you hover over one, the title gets removed. So if you hover over one to right click and inspect it, it won't have a title, because you hovered over it. The tags on this question and in the right column *do* have titles.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks :)